# Problem with picking HTML element with cheerio.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, backend, cheerio

I am really having trouble with picking a specifik element with cheerio.js

I managed to pick some other parts from this website, but for some reason i just cant get this right.

The element i am trying to get its the attr on the div element with the class"slick-slide slick-current slick-active" i would like to get the content attr, so i can grab the img link.

I also tried to use the find() method on #fixed-content and tried to find all div's inside. For some reason it didnt show up.

The link to the page is: https://home.dk/boligkatalog/ringsted/4100/huse-villaer/koegevej_221_fjaellebro_2060000853.aspx

Here is my current solution

I hope you guys can help!

```
async function webScraper() {


const resultArray = []
const propertyUrl = "https://home.dk/boligkatalog/ringsted/4100/huse-villaer/koegevej_221_fjaellebro_2060000853.aspx"



await axios(propertyUrl).then((res) => {
        
        const html = res.data

        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        const selected = "#fixed-content > div.col-lg-9.col-md-12.col-sm-12.alpha.omega.gallery-container > div > div.gallery-view.slick-initialized.slick-slider > div > div > div.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active" 

        const result = $(selected).attr();
    
        console.log(result)
    
        //Converts the href attribute from object to a string
        //JSON.stringify(result)
    
        console.log(typeof(result))
        
    
        //push to array
        resultArray.push(result)
 
    })


return [resultArray];

}
```

Comment: That class isn't in the static HTML. You probably want Puppeteer.

Comment: @ggorlen And there is no way to pick non static elements with cheerio?

Comment: No. If you do `console.log(html)` you won't see your element. It's injected by JS, and cheerio isn't a JS engine, just a static HTML parser. So it parses only whatever's in the `html` string and nothing more. You can use a utility that executes JS, like a web browser.